# Google App Engine: Extracting the value of the radio button chosen

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm building an application which allows users to create surveys and vote on the questions of the surveys. Now, the answers to those questions will be stored in the datastore so that I can analyze the results in the end. However, I am unable to figure out a way to extract the value of the radio button chosen by the user. Each question has three options, all of whom represented by a radio button.

Here's the code:

main.py

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2
from google.appengine.ext import db
from random import randint

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape=True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)
    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)
    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

#databases

class Survey(db.Model):
    vam_id = db.StringProperty()
    subject = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    description = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    q1 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o11 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o12 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o13 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    q2 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o21 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o22 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o23 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    q3 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o31 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o32 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o33 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    q4 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o41 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o42 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o43 = db.TextProperty(required = True) 
    q5 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o51 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o52 = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    o53 = db.TextProperty(required = True)

class Votes(db.Model):
    vam_id = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    q1_opt = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    q2_opt = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    q3_opt = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    q4_opt = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    q5_opt = db.TextProperty(required = True)



class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("homepage.html")

class NewSurvey(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("newsurvey.html")
    def post(self):
        vam_id = str(randint(1, 500))
        subject = self.request.get("title")
        description = self.request.get("description")
        q1 = self.request.get("q1")
        o11 = self.request.get("o11")
        o12 = self.request.get("o12")
        o13 = self.request.get("o13")
        q2 = self.request.get("q2")
        o21 = self.request.get("o21")
        o22 = self.request.get("o22")
        o23 = self.request.get("o23")
        q3 = self.request.get("q3")
        o31 = self.request.get("o31")
        o32 = self.request.get("o32")
        o33 = self.request.get("o33")
        q4 = self.request.get("q4")
        o41 = self.request.get("o41")
        o42 = self.request.get("o42")
        o43 = self.request.get("o43") 
        q5 = self.request.get("q5")
        o51 = self.request.get("o51")
        o52 = self.request.get("o52")
        o53 = self.request.get("o53")

        a = Survey(vam_id = vam_id, subject = subject, description = description, q1 = q1,
                    o11 = o11, o12 = o12, o13 = o13, q2 = q2,
                    o21 = o21, o22 = o22, o23 = o23, q3 = q3,
                    o31 = o31, o32 = o32, o33 = o33, q4 = q4,
                    o41 = o41, o42 = o42, o43 = o43, q5 = q5,
                    o51 = o51, o52 = o52, o53 = o53)
        a.put()            

class Existing(Handler):
    def get(self):
        surveys = Survey.all()
        self.render("existingsurvey.html", surveys = surveys)

class PermaSurvey(Handler):
    def get(self):
        vam = self.request.get("vam_id")
        su = Survey.all().filter("vam_id =", vam).get()
        self.render("perma.html", su = su)
    def post(self):
        vam = self.request.get("vam_id")
        q1_opt = self.request.get("q1")
        q2_opt = self.request.get("q2")
        q3_opt = self.request.get("q3")
        q4_opt = self.request.get("q4")
        q5_opt = self.request.get("q5")

        v = Votes(vam_id = vam, q1_opt = q1_opt, q2_opt = q2_opt, q3_opt = q3_opt,
                    q4_opt = q4_opt, q5_opt = q5_opt)  
        v.put()     

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/new', NewSurvey),
                               ('/existing', Existing),
                               ('/perma', PermaSurvey)], debug=True)
```

perma.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Perma Survey</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method = "post">
    {% block content %}
        <h2>{{su.subject}}</h2>
        <p>{{su.description}}</p>
        <br>
        {{su.q1}}
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="q1">{{su.o11}}<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q1">{{su.o12}}<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q1">{{su.o13}}
        <hr>
        {{su.q2}}
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="q2">{{su.o21}}<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q2">{{su.o22}}<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q2">{{su.o23}}
        <hr>
        {{su.q3}}
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="q3">{{su.o31}}<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q3">{{su.o32}}<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q3">{{su.o33}}
        <hr>
        {{su.q4}}
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="q4">{{su.o41}}<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q4">{{su.o42}}<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q4">{{su.o43}}
        <hr>
        {{su.q5}}
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="q5">{{su.o51}}<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q5">{{su.o52}}<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q5">{{su.o53}}
        <hr>
        <br>
        <input type = "submit">
    {% endblock %}
</form>    
</body>
</html>
```

Now, no matter what options I select from the three listed ones, the value that's stored in the datastore is 'on', indicating that a radio button from the radio button group is selected. How can I store the actual choices that were chosen by the user into the datastore ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not assigned any `value`s to your form elements.  I think you want:

```
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="{{su.o31}}" />{{su.o31}}<br>
```

Now, you can retrieve it's `value`.  Since you're already using jinja, I suggest you use the WTForms package to make this all easier.